# Return two data attributes from same div

Tags: jquery

How would I return two data attributes of the same div? In my code below I am returning the the value of data-color from a div. I also want to return the data-background attribute from the same div so I can use this in part 'css: background-color: [data-background value here]';

How would I do this in my code below?

```
var colors = $("div").map(function() {
  return $(this).data("color");
});

var backgrounds = $("div").map(function() {
  return $(this).data("background");
});

var $ul = $("ul#slideImages"),
$swatches = $(".swatches");
$.each(colors, function(i, color) {
  var $li = $("<li/>", {
    class: color
  });
  $ul.append(new Array(7).join($li.get(0).outerHTML));
  $swatches.append($("<swatch/>", {
    text: color,
    css: {
      "background-color": backgrounds
    },
    on: {
      click: function() {
        $('ul#slideImages li.' + $(this).text()).prependTo('ul#slideImages');
      }
    }
  }))
});
```

So, these answers don't seem to be working so I try and change and simplify the problem:

I have two loops and I want to loop through loop1 and insert it's data-attribute value into loop2. Using the below how could I do this?

```js
$(".groupA[data-background]").each(function(i){
   var backgroundData = $(this).data('background');
})


$(".groupB").each(function(i){
   var insertedBackground = $(this).attr('style');   
})
```

Comment: just like in other programming-languages you can use an [array](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/):
`var myArray2 = [ "color", "background" ];`

Answer (score 1):

Have a single function that returns a map of objects with both `color` and `background` properties, and iterate over that collection instead:

```
var attribs = $("div").map(function () {
    return {
        color: $(this).data("color"),
        background: $(this).data("background")
    };
});

var $ul = $("ul#slideImages"),
$swatches = $(".swatches");
$.each(attribs, function (i, attrib) {
    var $li = $("<li/>", {
        class: attrib.color
    });
    $ul.append(new Array(7).join($li.get(0).outerHTML));
    $swatches.append($("<swatch/>", {
        text: attrib.color,
        css: {
            "background-color": attrib.background
        },
        on: {
            click: function () {
                $('ul#slideImages li.' + $(this).text()).prependTo('ul#slideImages');
            }
        }
    }))
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the way to go except it seems to be looping twice for the background too. The output I want is:

<swatch style="background-color: some-data-from-data-background;">Blue</swatch>

The list item is produced separately like this:

<li class="blue">...</li>

Answer (score 0):

hi please try this solution :

1) create an array variable.

2) fill your values in the array.

3) return the array.

4) access the values from the array.

Comment: But I wanted to use the .map() method as used in the colors to keep in consistent. Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: sorry i didn't read the question properly, Just answered in hurry, I am working now, If i get some time by evening then i shall definitely try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can only return *one* thing from a function, though through use of an array, or an object, you can return many separate things contained within that *one* thing:

```
var colors = $("div").map(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  return {
    'color' : self.data('color'),
    'background' : self.data('background');
  }
});
```

And then access the values with:

```
colors[index].color,
colors[index].background
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi  your question doesn't seem to relate to the example code.

are you defining your div in html?
eg

```
<div id='id' data-background='#RRGGBB' data-color='#RRGGBB'>content</div>
```

then you can reference this with jquery, eg

```
var b = $('#id').data('background');
var c = $('#id').data('color');
```

or, if using javascript to store the data attributes, just use the data set method

```
$('#id').data('color','#RRGGBB').data('background','#RRGGBB');
```

Comment: Yes, the divs are being generated from another data source so I am grabbing the values of these divs from the html to put into this JQuery, so I need to loop through all these divs

Comment: Well it's using Shopify's liquid so won't really make sense but here goes:

<div data-color="{{ value | escape }}" class="swatch" data-background="{{ value | split: ' ' | last | handle }}; background-image: url( {{ value | handle | append: '.' | append: file_extension | asset_url }})" >

Comment: i can't work out why you are making a TAG called $("<swatch/>",..    why not just iterate through the divs with class of swatch and add to whereever it is going, eg $('div.swatches').each(function(index,element){b = $(this).data('background'); var c = $(this).data('color'); etc... });